# Searching for a string in a specified file extension with conditions

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I'm currently grepping a directory looking for a specific string that is only present in .txt files. However, I'd like to expand my grep to only return values where the directory contains specific file type. For example, my existing grep:

```
grep -R abc1234 --include=\*.txt
```

But I'd want to limit my return results to only include directories that contain, for example, PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, use the `find` command to locate directories that contain a `.pdf` file. The `-name` option is used to search for files with the `.pdf` extension, and the `-type d` option ensures that find only returns directories. The `-exec` option allows us to perform an action on each item found. In this case, the action is to apply the grep command to the directory.

   ```
   find . -name "*.pdf" -type d -exec
   ```
2. Next, add the `grep` command. The `-R` option makes grep search recursively in the directory, `--include=*.txt` restricts the search to `.txt` files, and `"abc1234"` is the string you're searching for.

   ```
   find . -name "*.pdf" -type d -exec grep -R --include=*.txt "abc1234" {} \;
   ```

The `{}` placeholder represents the current directory found by `find`, and `\;` signifies the end of the `-exec` command.

This command will first find all directories that contain a `.pdf` file, and then `grep` will search those directories for `.txt` files containing the string `"abc1234"`.